# Render anchor or button depending on variable, with same content inside

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

I want to render in lwc:

```
< a href...>
content1
< /a>
```

or

```
< button oncli...>
content1
< /button>
```

content1 consists of about 30 lines of code. I don't want to just use `if:true` `if:false` and paste same content in two tags, I am looking for something like this:
if true - print < a> with content1, if false, print < button> with content1.
I can't in that case extract content1 to separate file.
Is it possible to conditionally render first or second tag depending on variable or save that content and use it in these to tags somehow (like slots)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to move `content1`, you can make a wrapper component for the button/anchor setup:

```
<template>
  <button if:true={isButton}>
    <slot></slot>
  </button>
  <a href={href} if:true={isLink}>
    <slot></slot>
  </a>
</template>
```

---

```
import { api, LightningElement } from 'lwc'

export default class ContentWrapper extends LightningElement {
  @api href
  @api isButton
  @api isLink
  
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/AmfWnRb8OVnVjt18dokQ/src/contentWrapper.js?p=stories) for you.

Unfortunately, this is the only other viable method in LWC. You must put either the wrapper or the content into a separate component. Note that native HTML events automatically bubble up to the top, so you can still put your onclick in the parent component. However, you will also need to check if you're currently in link or button mode separately at that point, to determine if the click should be handled.